Should the normal vector be included for covariant derivative of tensors on a surface?
I am studying tensors from P. Grinfeld's "Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces". Currently, I am having trouble with finding the covariant derivative for tensors on surfaces embedded in an ambient space (hypersurface). In Chapter 11, Equation 11.1, he provides the expression for the covariant derivative of a mixed tensor of rank (1,1). Specifically, we get:
$\nabla_{\gamma} T^\alpha = \frac{\partial T^\alpha}{\partial S^\gamma} + \Gamma^\alpha_{\gamma \beta} T^{\beta} $
where alpha, beta and gamma are surface indices.
My question is, since the Christoffel symbol on right hand side, does not take into account the normal to the surface component, shouldn't the equation rather be
$\nabla_{\gamma} T^\alpha = \frac{\partial T^\alpha}{\partial S^\gamma} + \Gamma^\alpha_{\gamma \beta} T^{\beta} + B^{\alpha}_{\gamma}N,$
where N is a normal vector to the surface, at that point ?

The author already answers your question in section 10.8. He defines the Christoffel symbol using ${\bf S}^\alpha \cdot \frac{\partial {\bf S}_\beta}{\partial S^\gamma}$ and so avoids the alternative definition in terms of vectors defined only on the tangent plane.
